# Why is my loop not running through the full list of unconfirmed_users and continuing to pop until the unconfirmed_users is empty?

Tags: python, loops

```
unconfirmed_users = ['mikey', 'ethan', 'bob']

confirmed_users = []

while unconfirmed_users:
    current_users = unconfirmed_users.pop()

print('Verifying user: ' + current_users.title())
confirmed_users.append(current_users)


print('\nThe following users have been verified: ')

for users in confirmed_users:
    print(users.title())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error in indentation, you should put current_user=... and the print statement inside the while loop block:

```
unconfirmed_users = ['mikey', 'ethan', 'bob']

confirmed_users = []

while unconfirmed_users:
    current_users = unconfirmed_users.pop()

    print('Verifying user: ' + current_users.title())
    confirmed_users.append(current_users)


print('\nThe following users have been verified: ')

for users in confirmed_users:
    print(users.title())
```

Output:

```
Verifying user: Bob
Verifying user: Ethan
Verifying user: Mikey

The following users have been verified: 
Bob
Ethan
Mikey
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop

```
while unconfirmed_users:
    current_users = unconfirmed_users.pop()
```

running through complete  `unconfirmed_users` because you've asked it do do that: while loop runs until condition is True. In Python `bool(list) == False` when list is epmty (has zero length).
So, just check the indents:

```
unconfirmed_users = ['mikey', 'ethan', 'bob']

confirmed_users = []

while unconfirmed_users:
    current_users = unconfirmed_users.pop()
    print('Verifying user: ' + current_users.title())
    confirmed_users.append(current_users)


print('\nThe following users have been verified: ')

for users in confirmed_users:
    print(users.title())
```